# Why doesn't work .toSet() to create a Collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I want to create a Collection of values from properties for a specific key. The methods works this way:

```
Collection<String> getValueOfKey(final Collection<Localization> input, final String key) {
        return input.stream().map(l -> {
            return l.getProperties();
        }).map(p -> {
            return p.getProperty(key, "");
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

First I wanted to use `Collectors.toSet()` instead of `Collectors.toList()` but then I got wrong results (It just gave me the value from `en`).  Does anybody know why I can't use `.toSet()`?

Here is my TestCode:

```
public class RowCreatorTest {
private final Properties fixturePropertieDe = new Properties();
private final Properties fixturePropertieEn = new Properties();
private final Localization de = new Localization(Languages.GERMAN, fixturePropertieDe);
private final Localization en = new Localization(Languages.ENGLISH, fixturePropertieEn);

private final RowCreator sut = new RowCreator();

@Before
public void prepareFixtures() {
    fixturePropertieDe.put("key1", "foo1");
    fixturePropertieDe.put("key3", "foo3");

    fixturePropertieEn.put("key1", "bar1");
    fixturePropertieEn.put("key2", "bar2");
}

@Test
public void getValueOfKey() {
    assertThat(sut.getValueOfKey(Arrays.asList(de, en), "key1"), contains("foo1", "bar1"));
    assertThat(sut.getValueOfKey(Arrays.asList(de, en), "key2"), contains("", "bar2"));
    assertThat(sut.getValueOfKey(Arrays.asList(de, en), "key3"), contains("foo3", ""));
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what the test said: [test screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Sps.jpg)

Comment: Using `Collectors.toSet()` definitely yields a `Collection`: `Collection<String> set = new ArrayList<String>().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());`. There's a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Could you give more detail describing what went wrong when you used `toSet()` ?

Comment: All three assertions failed? Only one of them?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the test failture

Comment: Looks more like your problem is, that you should use `containsInAnyOrder` and not `contains`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the link to the error you posted (`expected iterable containing ["foo1","bar1"] but item 0 was "bar1"`), the assertion expected the two values to appear in the specified order (first "foo1", then "bar1"), but `Set`s don't maintain order, and "bar1" appeared first when iterating over the `Set`, so the assertion failed.

Hence the problem is in the assertion, not in the use of `toSet()`.

You could force the `Set` to be iterated according to insertion order if, for example, you use a `LinkedHashSet` (replace `toSet()` with `toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)`). This would ensure the assertion doesn't fail.

Comment: "bangig head on my desk" Oh! Thank you!

Comment: Or better yet, use [`containsInAnyOrder()`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(T...)) instead of [`contains()`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(E...)).